# Error on Wildfly 11

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, wildfly

I got my WAR and EJB joined in EAR. Now when I run the server to test my xhtml files this comes up and nothing opens. I tried a lot of things but none of them worked, like changing standalone.xml file, restarting and reopen Wildfly, deleting files in wildfly/standalone/deployments.

I really need help with this one.

**Error:**

```
18:11:03,857 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.6.1.Final
18:11:04,169 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.7.SP1
18:11:04,310 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 11.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 3.0.8.Final) starting
18:11:05,778 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
18:11:05,785 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 2) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
18:11:05,801 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 11) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.1.6.Final
18:11:05,863 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0004: Found FitnesEAR.ear in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called FitnesEAR.ear.dodeploy
18:11:05,910 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
18:11:05,926 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO version 3.5.4.Final
18:11:05,926 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.5.4.Final
18:11:05,973 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 43) WFLYRS0016: RESTEasy version 3.0.24.Final
18:11:05,973 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
18:11:06,020 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.4.6.Final)
18:11:06,051 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
18:11:06,051 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
18:11:06,051 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYTX0013: The node-identifier attribute on the /subsystem=transactions is set to the default value. This is a danger for environments running multiple servers. Please make sure the attribute value is unique.
18:11:06,051 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
18:11:06,066 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
18:11:06,066 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=5.0.2.Final
18:11:06,113 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 36) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.4)
18:11:06,113 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
18:11:06,160 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
18:11:06,176 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
18:11:06,191 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.4.18.Final starting
18:11:06,410 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'C:\AISV\wildfly-11.0.0.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
18:11:06,660 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
18:11:06,660 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 64 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
18:11:06,660 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
18:11:06,738 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
18:11:06,754 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
18:11:06,754 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.5.Final
18:11:06,816 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
18:11:06,841 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYPAT0050: WildFly Full cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
18:11:06,872 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYDM0111: Keystore C:\AISV\wildfly-11.0.0.Final\standalone\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
18:11:06,872 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\AISV\wildfly-11.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments
18:11:06,888 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "FitnesEAR.ear" (runtime-name: "FitnesEAR.ear")
18:11:07,185 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
18:11:07,263 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0207: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "Fitnes.war")
18:11:07,263 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
18:11:07,497 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
18:11:07,608 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.9.Final (Apache CXF 3.1.12) 
18:11:08,030 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for Fitnes
18:11:08,151 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment FitnesEAR.ear
18:11:08,213 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-5) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.3.5.Final
18:11:08,370 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."FitnesEAR.ear"."Fitnes.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."FitnesEAR.ear"."Fitnes.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "Fitnes.war" of deployment "FitnesEAR.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:172)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/Message
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at org.jboss.as.jsf.deployment.JSFManagedBeanProcessor.deploy(JSFManagedBeanProcessor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:165)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.Message from [Module "deployment.FitnesEAR.ear.Fitnes.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    ... 11 more

18:11:08,526 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-1) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.8.Final
18:11:08,776 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
18:11:08,838 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "FitnesEAR.ear")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"FitnesEAR.ear\".\"Fitnes.war\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"Fitnes.war\" of deployment \"FitnesEAR.ear\"
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/Message
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.Message from [Module \"deployment.FitnesEAR.ear.Fitnes.war\" from Service Module Loader]"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"FitnesEAR.ear\".beanmanager",
        "jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.MySQL_home"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"FitnesEAR.ear\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"FitnesEAR.ear\".beanmanager]",
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"FitnesEAR.ear/Fitnes.war#Fitnes\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.MySQL_home]"
    ]
}
18:11:08,854 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "FitnesEAR.ear" (runtime-name : "FitnesEAR.ear")
18:11:08,854 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."FitnesEAR.ear".beanmanager (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."FitnesEAR.ear".weld.weldClassIntrospector] 
      service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.MySQL_home (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."FitnesEAR.ear/Fitnes.war#Fitnes".__FIRST_PHASE__] 
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.subunit."FitnesEAR.ear"."Fitnes.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "Fitnes.war" of deployment "FitnesEAR.ear"

18:11:08,932 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
18:11:08,932 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
18:11:08,932 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
18:11:08,932 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 11.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 3.0.8.Final) started (with errors) in 5419ms - Started 359 of 591 services (4 services failed or missing dependencies, 351 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
18:11:16,087 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0236: Suspending server with no timeout.
18:11:16,091 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
18:11:16,091 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Management Triggered Shutdown) WFLYSRV0241: Shutting down in response to management operation 'shutdown'
18:11:16,091 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
18:11:16,107 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0019: Host default-host stopping
18:11:16,107 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = h2
18:11:16,138 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTPS listener https suspending
18:11:16,138 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTPS listener https stopped, was bound to 127.0.0.1:8443
18:11:16,138 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTP listener default suspending
18:11:16,138 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTP listener default stopped, was bound to 127.0.0.1:8080
18:11:16,154 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0004: Undertow 1.4.18.Final stopping
18:11:16,154 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 16) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped client-mappings cache from ejb container
18:11:16,154 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0208: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: Fitnes.war) in 61ms
18:11:16,154 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment FitnesEAR.ear (runtime-name: FitnesEAR.ear) in 62ms
18:11:16,169 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0050: WildFly Full 11.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 3.0.8.Final) stopped in 54ms
```

Comment: Are you running with `standalone-full.xml`?  JMS is not enabled in `standalone.xml`.

Comment: I tried but it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the module dependency in your ear and specifically in a MANIFEST file inside your ear. Try again with your MANIFEST file containing this `Dependencies` entry.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Dependencies: javax.jms.api
```

Comment: This should definitely not be required.

Comment: what's the exception  now?

Comment: WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.subunit."FitnesEAR.ear"."Fitnes.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "Fitnes.war" of deployment "FitnesEAR.ear"

Comment: yes. but before the error was java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/Message. what is the exact error now?

Answer (score 0):

The standalone.xml configuration does not include the JMS service. You need to use the standalone-full.xml configuration in order to include JMS.